# Infer properties of object passed to class constructor (typescript)

Tags: typescript

I have the following situation:

```
abstract class A {
    obj;

    constructor(obj:{[index:string]:number}) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super({i:0})
    }

    method() {
        //Here I would like intellisense to only suggest this.obj.i
    }
}
class C extends A {
    constructor() {
        super({i:0,j:0})
    }

    method() {
        //Here I would like intellisense to only suggest this.obj.i and this.obj.j
    }
}
```

I would like in `class B` to get autocompletion for the object passed in the constructor and likewise for `class C`. Is there a way to do this, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: You can try [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nab2pm) too, if you want to have the minimum of redundant type annotations; if you like that I can write up an answer explaining it.  Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `generic` `A` class like this:

```js
abstract class A<T extends Record<string, number> = Record<string, number>> {
    obj: T;

    constructor(obj:T) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}

class B extends A<{ i: number }> {
    constructor() {
        super({i:0})
    }

    method() {
        //Here I would like intellisense to only suggest this.obj.i
    }
}
class C extends A<{ i: number, j: number }> {
    constructor() {
        super({i:0,j:0})
    }

    method() {
        //Here I would like intellisense to only suggest this.obj.i and this.obj.j
    }
}
```

Play [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&module=100&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggHgCoIFMAPCAgOwBMMAlA2Aeygu0igEsyBzAGgTIFcAtiAJQAfAgC8CWgyYtoHHnyEjxEgN4BYAFAJ9CeiABWALgS4A3Lt0Gk9Mq37xGACiNncASgTa9dgwgACzYwADoPKUMTa399AF9dRJ1dFDQMACFCEnIqLGwNBDZzAWFRBHjNWwMGR2hnCDcfPwCDMH4AB1FXDWKABnivaoSbOIRBAmD6Cldm4YCAegWACVECBABJBAB3en5kCgRkNgBrdY5SZGOwchuERsMyZABPBHbOTgJIe5DwjzC2PNksk0ugEABhbKkSgYHCFYoqMpQXhmRFqCpVMa1JwuKCzXzzOztLp43qmPrcMwDIZjZLzCZTGZzMZ2JarKDrLa7faHY5nIpkS7XW7rB4OF5vfgfL6IYKhCImAEIYCUH7y-7GIFJIA)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=91&ssc=3&pln=91&pc=34#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-AA1YDIJhkaXKADC1hYZ2ANR8ADdM9KaGRgUaEBXkMQAO7WWscfkWmrC0X1yvVvK5fIN5vWPQpKDZwwIZSZsBkVEh5ZJFppZ551IhADWfMSaKJWxg8AzWbIADEoIXJdC1PlpfYQhBMg3s2AfLaoPa7HFBLt5E-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-m0kr+rIlkWsP0BeT5F5T-hJdz5Fj5XcvROr4I69yZvFp-ldQEJWiBVigIIUQOPzxJ7TzgjEP+p9CzAIdElMqS4CQVHfCXMuIdiR1yrjXZBQ1UENxes3Dk-k27PF7l3d8RC5aD1Asgg8XkAGTyvA9S+Wl56ZEXq+d8n416oRIS-NE29rC73qgfPclCwGOVofg2ejDr7mTIKw-y7DH6cP8kQre0iP7JW-vwKh8AaFnzoRwEBWjvKiN0eIuw2gFwpiSCaGgx9tKIDIMtTMe1XiwAvOgDasANywE3EcNxYAjJCSOjAOxABRRx1wWI7jVMkDErd7BBxYQKMCACkI4ziXYdurUfC7DiJkP+OiIEX3sMlfcdgUn5DSUUjJhCskM1yfkieZ9IGOCDr2PSSTKHCDUqkom6TMmd2yfUkeJ9jGFIyHBEplC7DdIqb0qp-TKA+DqXk4ZsUTxAKqclfKYxmiYNqIKWu+yIYwAMvY8JzikBeJ8YfShdlipMFXAw6JaIRAAMDF0xyA5ZmcTHC0dSkgZzIDnMaCo38MB-NDIIMpYNAzTM+YOb5WQzH6D+VOQFc50SgqFDZcFJUBTQNgTE+BpjWmJJuc0N4eioDlKLgqUxCyu45JWcfbRjS-L0OKR0ildgqU0pxgg+wDKllDJZf-NlLAqUTNabfLlkBKX+WPD07UArqlEMGcy6S4CJWmMmdyqlirEV0o5aq2pIrNWjO1carZWLDkHWOcAU55BzksUuVuWViB3z3MeRI55yQRC8phUofVmYvm0t1CikqaLZxkDVi8nl-k3mSHjQ9A1g5aXIvHJOAF0b8VewtLEmRdd6TTnaPax1i9ShXSdUwJxLEBQaLuROb1ZiEVSH8l61IzwS4RqzdOaNeUsWpSKiVAAhDAwu6SXA13uNQSV9hJ4ABEdmh1qNPAAskKVI1gGBRISWDMA7q3h8rmeMwVNSBlMoaYAppmzD3QteIavp57FnLKvRs09LT80VBleSuVHyTxKqyE+tVl7VlGPWTej9uq5VwoA4++Zz6u6vrA1q5p1qDkYNaPs9BuysN2psSc+e1ba0uKufW7FPZfVEFeYGt4alY1+vvbCtSubWmjQgNNDAlAYRRQOmAVIwAYQIAAGQgzBpWz5q0QDWAPYSuBQgAAy0oADigZfUYmSAAImEJpx2kcGMaaIJpuwunc581aUsIglj5MqqnSEGdZA50moGeQzFYml6HuEAGh9tKVVCtA6Kgplr9Gct-YgZNHBj3KvpYh4VGrqHiqc+hn9QiKVeYVfC3zMWQNmpGRB9lIXP2pZg8GuDWXjVCuQ6KrVSXyOpV3Oqf1CbaPpZTY5Bj1GIvUto11ljiULHslAn4gJNRgggCYMIZAMl8KYHoE5h8r5XMNqJtOsgF1HOmMXculBq78IbrSNuxbXyn7alW+tpzQq4ihh7aVVC2agXzmTG5sFJBR1jvwEsSq1hrDIDW2KWu7QmwwDOA9Oac4+OiFgANTM1xi2dQxSwTdh2ECwwOw8lqe1hBOIAF5yH6iwFHcM+qzTzOTDAsAJp4QvE2cgOJvCyeOD9sgmQzr73WN937E0fDVhp+sdVK5O3ri3HEFEbnghDte9md7jPfss+sGzjnf3udkBp3mHwKcYgx15rk1xMn-EuSEmNibU3p6zboPN+AYARcDpSjiyXZB3tAA)

UPDATED for a more comprehensive solution. The comments within the code showcase this in more detail, but essentially using (a) the generic defined in class A as well as (b) `public readonly i: _type_def_` etc. is advisable because it allows you to key-into targeted key-val pairs of interest. In Class C you can now enter `this.i` or `this.j`. Additionally, you can also use the `Object` constructor methods to deconstruct and reconstruct super.obj vs this.obj properties, testing along the way for inter-and-intra-object equality.

It isn't possible without writing additional advanced TS generics (to unwrap/infer object fields) to key into `this.obj.i` without first using the `Object` constructor methods to deconstruct and reconstruct the fields of the Record<string, number>. It *is* possible to key into `this.obj` or by using

```
// for key "i" and its value

const iValue = Object.values(this.obj)[0].valueOf();
const iKey = Object.keys(this.obj)[0].toString();

// to make this.obj.i, you reconstruct with the key/val

const thisObjI = { [iKey]: iValue }
```

```
abstract class A<
  T extends number extends { [index: string]: infer U } ? U : number
> {
  obj;

  constructor(obj: Record<string, T>) {
    this.obj = obj;
  }
  // [inferred]
  // constructor A<T extends number>(obj: Record<string, T>): A<T>
}

class B extends A<0> {
  constructor(public readonly i: number extends infer U ? U : number) {
    super({ i: 0 });
    // [inferred]
    // constructor A<0>(obj: Record<string, 0>): A<0>
  }

  stringify() {
    return JSON.stringify(
      {
        i: this.i as number, // i: number
        sup: super.obj as Record<string, 0> // sup: { [x: string]: 0; }
      },
      null,
      2
    );
  }

  objValueOfCompare(valOne: number, valTwo: number) {
    return valOne === valTwo ? true : false;
  }

  truthyCheck() {
    const extractValueFromSuper = Object.values(super.obj)[0].valueOf();
    const iIsValueOfObjRecord = <
      T extends typeof this.i extends Record<string, infer U>
        ? U
        : typeof this.i
    >(
      objectCompare: T
    ) => {
      const extractThisInjectedObjectValue =
        Object.values(objectCompare)[0].valueOf();
      return this.objValueOfCompare(
        extractValueFromSuper,
        extractThisInjectedObjectValue
      );
    };
    return iIsValueOfObjRecord; // returns True
  }
}

// By declaring each index of the super obj in the constructor 
// you can input a unique comma-delimited Int/Float value on a
// per field basis -- `new C(1, 2)` etc.. This allows you to 
// key into fields within the Record -- eg, `this.i` or `this.j`

class C extends A<3.14 | -7.28> {
  constructor(
    public readonly i: number extends infer U ? U : number,
    public readonly j: number extends infer U ? U : number
  ) {
    super({ i: 3.14, j: -7.28 });

    // [inferred]:
    // constructor A<3.14 | -7.28>(obj: Record<string, 3.14 | -7.28>): A<3.14 | -7.28>
  }

  // thisObj deconstruction/reconstruction helper
  thisObjByIndex(thisIndex: number) {
    const extractKeyFromThisObj = Object.keys(this.obj)[
      thisIndex
    ].toString();
    const extractValueFromThisObj = Object.values(this.obj)[
      thisIndex
    ].valueOf();
    return { extractKeyFromThisObj, extractValueFromThisObj };
  }

  // superObj deconstruction/reconstruction helper
  superObjByIndex(superIndex: number) {
    const extractKeyFromSuperObj = Object.keys(super.obj)[
      superIndex
    ].toString();
    const extractValueFromSuperObj = Object.values(super.obj)[
      superIndex
    ].valueOf();
    return { extractKeyFromSuperObj, extractValueFromSuperObj };
  }

  // intraObject equality cross-check
  crossCompareIntraObjectEquality() {
    // thisObj
    //keys
    const iKey = this.thisObjByIndex(0).extractKeyFromThisObj;
    const jKey = this.thisObjByIndex(1).extractKeyFromThisObj;
    // values
    const iValue = this.thisObjByIndex(0).extractValueFromThisObj;
    const jValue = this.thisObjByIndex(1).extractValueFromThisObj;
    // reconstructed intraobject equality check
    const thisTruthyObj = {
      [iKey]: iValue === this.i ? true : false, // returns true
      [jKey]: jValue === this.j ? true : false // returns true
    };

    // superObj
    // keys
    const iSuperKey = this.superObjByIndex(0).extractKeyFromSuperObj;
    const jSuperKey = this.superObjByIndex(1).extractKeyFromSuperObj;
    // values
    const iSuperVal = this.superObjByIndex(0).extractValueFromSuperObj;
    const jSuperVal = this.superObjByIndex(1).extractValueFromSuperObj;
    // reconstructed intraobject equality check
    const superTruthyObj = {
      [iSuperKey]: iSuperVal === this.i ? true : false,
      [jSuperKey]: jSuperVal === this.j ? true : false
    };

    // testing for intraobject key/value equality
    return thisTruthyObj === superTruthyObj ? true : false; // returns True!
  }

  // thisObj
  recreateSuperObjFromDeconstructedThisMethods() {
    //keys
    const iKey = this.thisObjByIndex(0).extractKeyFromThisObj;
    const jKey = this.thisObjByIndex(1).extractKeyFromThisObj;
    // values
    const iValue = this.thisObjByIndex(0).extractValueFromThisObj;
    const jValue = this.thisObjByIndex(1).extractValueFromThisObj;
    // reconstructed intraobject equality check
    return {
      [iKey]: iValue,
      [jKey]: jValue
    };
    // outputs expected shape & key/value combos

    // [LOG]: {
    //    "i": 3.14,
    //    "j": -7.28
    // }
  }

  // superObj
  recreateSuperObjByIndex() {
    // keys
    const iSuperKey = this.superObjByIndex(0).extractKeyFromSuperObj;
    const jSuperKey = this.superObjByIndex(1).extractKeyFromSuperObj;
    // values
    const iSuperValue = this.superObjByIndex(0).extractValueFromSuperObj;
    const jSuperValue = this.superObjByIndex(1).extractValueFromSuperObj;
    return {
      [iSuperKey]: iSuperValue,
      [jSuperKey]: jSuperValue
    };
  }

  crossCompareRebuiltThisAndSuperObjects() {
    return this.recreateSuperObjFromDeconstructedThisMethods() ===
      this.recreateSuperObjByIndex()
      ? true
      : false;
  } // returns True!!
}
// Boolean constructor wrapper used since instantiating these 
// methods outside of an initialized Class can throw errors.
console.log(Boolean(new B(0).truthyCheck)); // Returns True!
console.log(Boolean(new C(3.14, -7.28).crossCompareRebuiltThisAndSuperObjects)); // returns True!
```

Comment: Both you and @Anatoly's answers are great, and I wish I could accept them both. Thank you.